Locally transfer files from mobile to webapp in reactjs using websockets
I want to create an webapp using reactjs where we can share files, contacts, images, videos etc from mobile to web and web to mobile using local network. Mobile app basically is a server to share files without internet like shareit, airdroid, zapya
The method is: Connect via ip address: for example http://192.168.100.3:8888. The phone and computer needs to be on same local network.
When a user enter this address in url (http://192.168.100.3:8888) at mobile app an popup open with accept or reject dialog. If user accept the connection the webapp will be hosted on that url that I mentioned above.It happen with each user ip address will be changed in case of each user.
When a request been send to user mobile app meanwhile a webpage will be open which is showing a message that a connection request been sent to your mobile app please accept.
I want to ask how this procedure works and How can I host my webapp on local ip address when the ip is not static it's a new one in case of each user.
Hope done with the question If have any query let me know. Thankyou any kind of help will be considerable and appreciated.
